# Elements of the right diagonal are not dispayning

Tags: arrays, c

I'm trying to display the elements of the right diagonal in 2d array, but the code shows only the first element of the diagonal. The problem is in if-clause if (i+j == 2), but I don't know how to solve it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main () {
    double a[100][100];
    int n, m;
    int i, j, b, c;
    srand (time (NULL));
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    scanf ("%d", &m);
    for (  i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (  j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = 0.09 * (rand () %1000) - 0.5;
        }
    }
    printf ("Array A[N][M]: \n");
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf ("\n");
        for ( j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf ("%6.0f", a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf ("\nElements of the right diagonal are: \n");
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for ( j = 0; i < m; j++)
        {
            if (i+j == n)
            {
                printf ("%6.0f\t", a[i][j]);
                return 0;
            }
        }  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Without return 0; in if-clause the code doesn't work at all

Hope for helping

I was trying to check various values in if-clause, but the situation hasn't changed

Comment: The `return 0;` inside the loop ends your program.

Comment: why do you have a return after the first printf

Comment: @tevemadar @ pm100 without return 0 the code doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems in the posted code

```
// ...
#include <cmath>       // That's a C++ header, while this question is tagged as C.

// ...
printf ("\nElements of the right diagonal are: \n");
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for ( j = 0; i < m; j++)
    { //         ^            There's no real need of a nested loop, but
      //                      in any case, the condition is wrong.
      //                      It should be 'j' there. 
        if ( i + j == n )
        { //       ^^^^   In the first version of the posted code (and the
          //              question) the condition was 'i+j==2'. Both are wrong.
          //              In a non-square matrix (where 'n != m') we might
          //              consider two anti-diagonals:
          //
          //                    j-> m               A              B
          //               +---A-------+        i      j       i      j
          //               |  /       /|      ------------    -----------
          //              i| /       / |        0    n - 1     0    m - 1
          //               |/       /  |        1    n - 2     1    m - 2
          //              n+-------B---+       ...    ...     ...    ...
          //                                  n - 1    0     n - 1  m - n  
          //
            printf ("%6.0f\t", a[i][j]);
            
            // The following return statement will end the loop.
            return 0;
        }
    }  
}
```

You could either fix the previous snippet:

```
printf ("\nElements of the right diagonal are: \n");
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for ( int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    { //             ^
        if ( i + j + 1 == m )
        { //       ^^^^^^^^
            printf ("%6.0f\t", a[i][j]);
        }
    }  
}
```

Or use a single loop:

```
printf ("\nElements of the anti-diagonal are: \n");

// Find the limiting dimension for non-square matrices.
int k = m < n ? m : n;

for ( int i = 0; i < k; ++i )
{
    printf("%6.0f\t", a[i][m - i - 1]);
    //                     ^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem:

```
printf ("\nElements of the right diagonal are: \n");
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        printf( "%6.0lf", a[n - j - 1][j] );
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't want to check if (i+j == 2), instead you should be checking if (i + j == n). Any point along the diagonal will have coordinates that add up to the size of the square.

Comment: I tried it too, but it displays 0 instead. Here is the example: 3
3
Array A[N][M]: 

    50    63    62
    51    40    80
    25    33    15
Elements of the right diagonal are: 
     0

Comment: I just read other comments - the return 0; in your loop will definitely be the cause of the issue.

Comment: but without return 0; it doesn't work at all..